# Two tableviews on the same screen

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am trying to work with `UITableView's`. What I am trying to achieve is to have two `UITableView's` on the same screen programmatically. My aim is to replicate  the contacts app on iPhone without using any predefined methods. Can anyone help me?

Comment: have you ever worked with `UITableView` before?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't achieved with multiple table views, it is one table with multiple sections. [Here's a tutorial](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/iphone-TableViewwithSection.html). Additionally, setting the tables style to `UITableViewStyleGrouped` is always an option as well if you're looking for a slightly different look.

Comment: can we reduce the width of a particular section then ??  for example if i want only the section==0 to have a smaller width means what should i do ? i triede this for 1 week and came to conclusion that we cant  is there any method ????? thanks

Comment: @user1591830 What do you mean by reduce width?

Comment: i want the first section to be of lesser width ..please refer adding a contact in iphone near to the photo u can see a section which has width  lesser than the other section...i want my first section to be like that is there any method ??

Comment: It doesn't have a different width, it just looks like it because of the way the elements are arranged.  If you make custom UITableViewCells, you can also arrange your content however your wish.

Comment: ok so there is no option for creating two tableview in a single view ?